# HTML / JavaScript = Age Group Identifier Code *problem

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, input

I am trying to do an activity in my web development class but I've ran into a problem that looks so simple but I seem to can't get my head around it. I've tried other solutions but still don't get what's wrong or lacking in my code.

I want my program to analyze the age and identify it, to overwrite on the paragraph id of agetext, the age group (children, early working age...)

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Age Group Identifier</h1>
<p></p>To find out the category of an age group, please enter the age below.</p>
<form id="agegroupidentifier">
    Age: <input id="agein" type="text"><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="ageInput();" value="Submit">
    <p ="agetext"></p>
</form>
<script>
    function ageInput() {
var ageInp=document.getElementById("agein").value;
    }
        if (agein =< 14) {
        document.getElementById("agetext").innerHTML="Children";
        }
        else (agein =< 24)
        document.getElementById("agetext").innerHTML="Early Working Age";
                }
        else (agein =< 54)
        document.getElementById("agetext").innerHTML="Prime Working Age";
                }
        else (agein =< 64)
        document.getElementById("agetext").innerHTML="Mature Working Age";
                }
        else (agein > 64)
        document.getElementById("agetext").innerHTML="Elderly";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the problem you have with your code?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code:

1. Your `p` tag appears to have a malformed `id` attribute. Change `<p ="agetext"></p>` to `<p id="agetext"></p>`
2. There are way more closing braces `}` then there are opening braces `{` - they should be matched.
3. The `agein` variable is never assigned and will always be undefined, may be ageInp should be renamed `agein`. Even better use `ageIn`.
4. The less than or equal operator is `<=` not `=<`.
5. The button input type will automatically attempt to submit the form unless you make a call to preventDefault() on the handlers event parameter.
6. Assuming `ageInp` should be `ageIn` you will need to parse the string value to a number to make meaningful numerical comparisons, otherwise all comparisons will be string based where `'10'` is less than `'3'`.
7. `else` clauses must be a complete `if ()` you cannot do `else ()`
8. `innerHTML` should probably be `innerText` unless you actually mean to create child HTML elements.
9. your first `p` element is immediately closed without enclosing the text along with an ignored trailing closing `</p>`

Along with all these changes, I would also only set `innerText` in a single place and use a variable to hold the appropriate text ready to insert in to the page.

```js
function ageInput(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var ageIn = parseInt(document.getElementById("AgeIn").value);
  var ageText = '';

  if (ageIn <= 14)
    ageText = "Children";
  else if(ageIn <= 24)
    ageText = "Early Working Age";
  else if (ageIn <= 54)
    ageText = "Prime Working Age";
  else if (ageIn <= 64)
    ageText = "Mature Working Age";
  else
    ageText = "Elderly";

  document.getElementById("AgeText").innerText = ageText;
}
```

```html
<h1>Age Group Identifier</h1>
<p>To find out the category of an age group, please enter the age below.</p>
<form id="agegroupidentifier">
  Age: <input id="AgeIn" type="text"><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="ageInput(event);" value="Submit">
  <p id="AgeText"></p>
</form>
```